# Override child div property thats set as parentClass>div{} with a seperate child class

Tags: css

I set property of all div tags inside a parent class using `parentClass>div{ }` method in css. Then i assign one of the div tag a seperate class named `child`. But anything i set in `child` doesnt affect that div tag.

```css
.parent>div {
  padding: 10%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.child {
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>something</div>
  <div class="child">CHILD</div>
</div>
```

How can I make `child` class effective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.parent>div` selector has a higher [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than the `.child` selector. You'll need a way to increase the specificity of `.child`. You could use `!important`.

Another way would be to just use the `.child` class twice in the selector, as below

```css
.parent>div {
  padding: 10%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.child.child {
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>something</div>
  <div class="child">CHILD</div>
</div>
```

Another way would be to use `.parent>div:not(.child)` to ignore styling `.child` elements which are direct children of `.parent`

```css
.parent>div:not(.child) {
  padding: 10%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.child {
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>something</div>
  <div class="child">CHILD</div>
</div>
```